# Java multiline scanner input

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, multiline

I have a specific problem regarding `Scanner` and its way of doing input from `System.in`.

**What I want to do:** I need to read a single input given from `System.in`. The problem is that this input can have more than one line (the input can have many `\n` characters).

**What I tried:**

The obvious thing I tried is `Scanner.nextLine()` method, but ofcourse, this will not read all data. The next thing I tried is this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(); 

while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if(line.isEmpty()){
        break;
    }
    data.add(line);
}
```

But this will also skip a lot of data - for instance, when there is an empty line in the middle of given text.

I also tried to remove the `break;` statement and hope that the `while(sc.hasNextLine())` loop will break itself, but this will never happen since scanner will wait for the data.

Can this be done in Java? Thanks for your time

Comment: The loop _will_ break itself. You just need to give it an end of line character.

Comment: maybe this is a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42429171/3959856

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read all input, on multiple lines, into a list of strings, one element per input line, then the user will have to indicate when the input has ended. This is often done by using the End-of-File character: on the Windows Command Prompt, it's Ctrl-Z, and on Linux, OS X and the IntelliJ IDE input window on all platforms, it's Ctrl-D.

You can read the lines with the following code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> data = sc.tokens().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you press Command + D on OS X or Control + D on Windows, you will insert an end of line character.

When the scanner reaches an end of line character, `hasNextLine` will return false and the loop will terminate.

So remove this:

```
if(line.isEmpty()){
    break;
}
```

and type an end of line character after your multi line input.

Alternatively, if this is allowed, you can put your input as a string to the scanner. For example, if you want to input this input:

```
Hello World
This is a
Multiline
input
```

You can initialise the scanner like this:

```
Scanner line = new Scanner("Hello World\n" +
        "This is a\n" +
        "Multiline\n" +
        "input");
```

Or you can put your input into a file and let the scanner read that:

```
Scanner line = new Scanner(new File("path to your input file"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this type for reading

```
String read = "";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        line = sc.nextLine();
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        read += line + "\n";
    }
    System.out.println(read);
```

Here, first we check is there nextline occurs or not. if yes then read data using sc.nextLine() method and if read data is blank then break loop.