# Reading multiple lines from scanner in Java

Tags: java

I have this piece of code:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter student name and ID#: " +line);

    String [] names = new String[20];

    for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
```

What I need is for it to print out 20 names and ID#'s from the scanner, but it only can print out one line.  I think I might be on the right track with the for loop, but I don't know where to go from here. I want it to look something like this when printed out:

```
Enter student name and ID#: John Smith 123456
                            Ashley Brown 234567
```

Etc...Up to 20 names and ID#'s.  I know there have been similar questions like this on here, but I haven't found one that's almost exact to my situation.  If I'm mistaken then please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: You'll need a loop.

Comment: That doesn't look like complete code – is there more? What you posted above reads a single line, print that one line, then creates an emtpy array and does something with the array in a loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading multiple lines into a scanner object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42429134/reading-multiple-lines-into-a-scanner-object-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

Use a for loop.

Something like:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String [] names = new String[20];

System.out.println("Enter student name and ID#:");

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
   String line = input.nextLine();

   names[i] = line;
}
```

Comment: You should probably move the `input.nextLine()` call to be after the print statement, because your current answer prompts for an input after the input has already been given. Also, you'd be better off printing out the entire array at the end rather than printing out the input in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @MihirKekkar you are right, I copied from their original, fixed.

Answer (score -1):

put both

```
`System.out.println("Enter student name and ID#: " +line);` 
 String line = input.nextLine();
```

inside the loop and put the valule for each nextLine into array names

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String [] names = new String[20];
            for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter student name and ID#: " +line);

            String line = input.nextLine();
        names[i]=line;}
```